# SQLite question? Podcast Producer server failure

Tags: mac-osx, database, sqlite

Suddenly this morning none of my recording machines can connect to the server.  There were no software updates on the client or server side this weekend.  It looked like a firewall issue at first, but the connection is being built and the PodPro server is not responding.

Podcast Producer uses a sqlite3 database that lives in /var/pcast/ and it looks from the logs as though this database is locked and not allowing access.

I have tried moving it to a temp location and copying it back to remove any file-level locks but that did not work.

Anyone have experience with Podcast Producer or SQLite out there?

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide an actual answer, but you could attempt to troubleshoot by copying the DB and trying to open it with some other SQLite client.  Firefox has a 'SQLite Manager' extension that can open and examine arbitrary .sqlite files, for example.

Note that I don't recommend opening the original file!  Make a copy and work with that as much as possible so that you don't mess with the application's data unintentionally.

Comment: Great advice!  Thanks.  Good to know about the Firefox extension.

I did manage to work around the problem by having Podcast Producer create a fresh DB - simply by renaming the existing database.